# Delete table and create table again

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax, syntax-error

I'm using MySQL 6.0 Workbench and having a problem while dropping a table if exists and creating a new table script.

Below is my sql script.

```
delimiter $$

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tableName`;
CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
  `column1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `column2` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`column1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Error message :

```
Syntax error near CREATE TABLE `tableName`
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS`, `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`, and `DROP VIEW IF EXISTS` statements are always replicated, even if the database, table, or view to be dropped does not exist on the master.

Comment: Can you show us your full SQL query

Comment: you should read this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-create-tables.htm and this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-drop-tables.htm

Comment: Is it `CHARSET=latin1$$`????

Comment: This is not the full query

Comment: Post full table structure otherwise no body can help you

Comment: Instead of asking the full structure so many times, it is better to close it

Comment: I've added a complete sql script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED Answer

You need to use delimiter `$$` in `DROP TABLE` statement as well

```
delimiter $$

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tableName`$$ 

CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
  `column1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `column2` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`column1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Comment: Remove $$ after `CHARSET=latin1`

Answer (score 1):

Use following sql :

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test(
  var1 int,
  var2 int
)
```

Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6e60

Comment: This doesn't work. Added the entire script to question

Answer (score 0):

this does work for me

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tableName`;

CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
  `column1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `column2` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`column1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1de74)

maybe you need to check your " ` "